# How to fix "NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0."

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, crash

I am creating a new iOS application using swift, and need help with getting my tableView to delete data.  I am using Core Data to save the data in a one-to-many relationship, and I have it so the entity selected deletes but it crashes when it updates the tableView.

I have created applications before but this is my first with using the one-to-many data storage method.  I have also Googled solution but none have worked.  Here is my code for my tableView editingStyle.

```
if editingStyle == .delete {
    context.delete(items[indexPath.row])

    do {
        try context.save()

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

I want the row to delete along with the entity in Core Data but it is actually just deleting the entity and then crashing when it tries to update the tableView. Specifically I think it is crashing when it calls "deleteRows" because it then gives the error:

> Project Aurora[14179:303873] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

More Code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count = fetchedRC.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0
    return count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemsTable", for: indexPath) as! ItemsTableViewCell

    items.append(fetchedRC.object(at: indexPath))

    if items[indexPath.row].isComplete == true {
        let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: items[indexPath.row].name!)

        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
        cell.nameL.attributedText = attributeString

    } else {
        cell.nameL.text = items[indexPath.row].name
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Try swapping the `item.remove...` and the `beginUpdates` lines.

Comment: That doesn't work either and I updated it with the full error and deleting the comment with the error to make it less cluttered.

Comment: Can you show your `numberOfRows` and `cellForRow` code?

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated the question with the numberOfRows and CellForRow included now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `NSFetchedResultsController`, so it isn't a good idea to maintain a separate array (your `items`) array; Just use the `object(at:)` method to get the item when required.

You also have an issue as you are appending the item to your `items` array in `cellForRowAt:` - `cellForRowAt:` will be called more than once for a given `indexPath` and there is no guarantee of the order in which `cellForRowAt:` is called (e.g. as you scroll the tableview).

If you are using an `NSFetchedResultsController` you really should implement its delegate and use the delegate methods to update your table.

Get rid of the `items` array and use something like:

```
extension ItemsTableViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        let newIndexPath: IndexPath? = newIndexPath != nil ? IndexPath(row: newIndexPath!.row, section: 0) : nil
        let currentIndexPath: IndexPath? = indexPath != nil ? IndexPath(row: indexPath!.row, section: 0) : nil

        switch type {
        case .insert:
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)

        case .delete:
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [currentIndexPath!], with: .fade)

        case .move:
            self.tableView.moveRow(at: currentIndexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)

        case .update:
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [currentIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Your `cellForRowAt` should be:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemsTable", for: indexPath) as! ItemsTableViewCell

    let item = fetchedRC.object(at:indexPath)

    if item.isComplete == true {
        let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: item.name ?? "")

        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
        cell.nameL.attributedText = attributeString

    } else {
        cell.nameL.text = item.name
    }

    return cell
}
```

and your deletion code should be:

```
if editingStyle == .delete {
    context.delete(fetchedRC.object(at:indexPath))

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Remember to assign `self` to `fetchedRC.delegate` when you create your fetched results controller.

Comment: ok thank you.  I implemented that and the deletion still works but it does not seem like the extension is being called when I delete a row.  Why would that be?  Just also as reference my view controllers name is "ItemsTableViewController" if that would be helpful with the extension.  I did also change the name of the extension to extend this view.

Comment: Did you assign `self` to `fetchedRC.delegate` ?

Comment: Also, I missed one required change in the deletion code - I have fixed it

Comment: I did not.  How do I assign `self`as `fetchedRC.delegate` or where would that be? And I noticed the requirement and changed it, thank you for pointing that out though.

Comment: Assuming that you are creating your fetched results controller in `viewDidLoad` or similar, you would just say `fetchedRC.delegate = self`

Comment: I am and I added that and it worked. It now deletes the data and removes it from the tableView.  Thank you so much for helping!